# Insert, delete, update from a pl/sql script use by PHP

Tags: php, oracle, plsql

I launch a pl/sql script by a PHP application but I notice when there is either an insert, an update or a delete in the script, the script stops. While there is no problem if I use this script directly in sqldeveloper.

Is there something particular to do in order to use insert, delete, update ?
Thanks

```
 procedure update_nbr_execution
 (dem_id in number)
 IS
 BEGIN
UPDATE BCN_DEMANDE_EXTRACTION
    SET nombre_execution = nvl(nombre_execution,0) + 1
    WHERE id = dem_id;
 END;
```

In my php file :

```
            $query = "BEGIN 
                        ecrire_requete(:demande_id, :p_nom); 
                    END;";

            $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
            $tabvars = oci_new_collection($conn,'MYTABLETYPE');
            oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p_nom', $tabvars, -1, SQLT_NTY);
            oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':demande_id', $_POST['demande_id']);
            oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

And `update_nbr_execution` is call by `ecrire_requete`.

There is a trigger involve in `update_nbr_execution`, a field date is automatically update with the fiel nbr_execution. May it come from the trigger ?

Edit : after isolating some part, I'm now getting this error : `ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger`. So it does come from the trigger which looks like this :

```
create or replace
TRIGGER BCN_FORMAT_NOM_FICHIER_BI
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON BCN_DEMANDE_EXTRACTION
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
BEGIN
if inserting then
  :new.FORMAT_NOM_FICHIER_DONNEES:='bcn_<nom_lot>_<id demande>_<n° version>_<description>_<date>.dat';
  :new.FORMAT_NOM_FICHIER_CONTROLE:='bcn_<nom_lot>_<id demande>_<n° version>_<date>.ctr';
  :new.FORMAT_NOM_FICHIER_JETON:='bcn_<nom_lot>_<id demande>_<n° version>_<date>.jet';
  :new.FORMAT_NOM_FICHIER_ZIP:='bcn_<nom_lot>_<id demande>_<n° version>_<date>';
  :new.CREATED_AT:=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YY');
  :new.UPDATED_AT:=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YY');
else
   :new.UPDATED_AT:=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YY');
end if;
END;
```

Comment: what do u mean by STOP ?

Comment: can you show Some Code ?

Comment: try to debug query and get what error its showing.

Comment: Echo your query out. Copy that in an PHPmyadmin or something simulair. From there on you can look what part is not working.

If you are looking for an order or some kind, I try to avoid all 3 things in one statement. A) it doesnt look clean and B) Code tends to get messy and might not work

Comment: I already tried to echo and copy the query in sqldeveloper, and the script works fine

Comment: It's probably asking for user input, such as a login/password, which sql server provides automagically. The prompt wouldn't appear in PHP.  What happens when you run the pl/sql script directly?

Comment: In sqldeveloper, the script just do what it needs to do. Nothing less, nothing more.

Comment: Do you connect via sqldeveloper at same use as user used on php connect?

Comment: Yes, I use the same login/password in both cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a date format issue.

If `CREATED_AT` and `UPDATED_AT` are both dates, then `= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YY')`
will convert SYSDATE to a string, and then implicitly convert the string back to a date.  The implicit date conversion
depends on NLS_DATE_FORMAT, which is set by each client.

You probably have SQL Developer set to use something like DD/MM/YY, but PHP is using something else.  If you just 
want to remove the time from SYSDATE, you should use `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` instead.